# Как перенести Tab Bar на верх

Tags: ios, swift

В стандарте кнопки тапбара расплагаются внизу view, как перенести Tab Bar на верхнюю часть экрана?

Comment: Вам нужно либо NavigationBar и туда добавлять компоненты, либо использовать простое view настроенное под вашу задачу и крепить ее вверху

Answer (score 0):

Нет такой возможности, либо делать навигейшен бар
Так как тап бар всегда находится внизу